# How can I test if an element is already visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the HTML code, I use jQuery to hide or display an element having an ID. How can I test if an element is already visible?

For example, we use `show()` to display an element having an ID. But before calling `show()`, I need to test  whether `show()` has been already used for that ID then how to compare?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#element').is(':hidden'); // boolean
```

Answer (score 2):

If the element is visible, show() won't do anything, so it's pretty low risk.  However, you can use the `:visible` or `:hidden` selector to find visible elements.

```
$('#myId:visible').hide();

$('#myId:hidden').show();
```

Using this in your selector, you can just fire off the show and hide methods and not worry about what is visible or not, because if you try to hide a `:hidden` element, you won't select anything so you won't *do* anything.