# How to change the title and html on slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML markup:

```
<a title="Hide comments" hreflang="1" class="comment-show-link" rel="tooltip" href="">Hide comments</a>
<a title="Hide comments" hreflang="2" class="comment-show-link" rel="tooltip" href="">Hide comments</a>
```

I'll like to change the title and HTML to "Show comments" on slideToggle but didn't know how. I write this code to show/hide a DIV:

```
$('.comment-show-link').click(function(e) {
        $('#comment-show-'+$(this).attr("hreflang")).slideToggle('slow');
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

But not know how to check if DIV is hidden or visible and in each case change title and HTML. Also I know that I can use text() or html() jQuery functions to achieve this but how? Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [How can I test if an element is already visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410211/how-can-i-test-if-an-element-is-already-visible) and [How to change the value of multiple html attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795945/how-to-change-the-value-of-multiple-html-attribute). To learn how certain jQuery methods work, **read their documentation**: http://api.jquery.com/text/, http://api.jquery.com/html/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.comment-show-link').click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var num = $this.attr('hreflang'); 
        $('#comment-show-'+num).slideToggle('slow', function(){
            if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
               // do something here
               // $this.attr('...', '...') 
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Nice, this works! Thanks points and accept answer goes to you @undefined

Comment: one last question, I'm trying to change the HTML but it changes for every element in the page I want to change only the one I clicked this is the code I'm using: http://pastebin.com/f0Nrrpfn what's wrong?

Comment: @ReynierPM there is nothing wrong with your code, do you have multiple elements with same IDs?